# It's good using tables to improvent cpu usage?

Tags: performance, lua

I got a simple question, it may be a stupid question but i just want to know... i'm beginner on lua.

So, for example i have 2 scripts.

1.

```
local text = ''
local level = getUserLevel(self)

if level < 10 then
text = 'Low level'
elseif level >= 10 and level < 20 then
text = 'Average Level'
elseif level >= 20 and level < 30 then
text = 'High Level'
end
sendMsg(self, text)
```

2.

```
  local a = {
    b = {
     [{1, 10}] = {text = "Low Level"},
     [{10, 20}] = {text = "Average Level"},
     [{20, 30}] = {text = "High Level"}
    }
  }
for k, v in pairs (a.b) do
if getUserLevel(self) >= k[1] and getUserLevel(self) < k[2] then
sendMsg(self, v.text)
end
```

Leaving aside if is more or less code, which one would be better to improve cpu usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one calls `getUserLevel` once. The second one calls it six times. This will probably be a determining factor here, but as always, just run it and measure.

That being said, those programs aren't equivalent. The second one allows the lookup table to be dynamically changed, while the first one is hardcoded. Comparing them is a bit like apples and oranges.

And ultimately, I don't think this function is going to be a hotspot of anything. If it isn't, then *don't optimize it*. Strive for maximum readability first. Simple as that.

Comment: How is the first one calling it `getUserLevel` twice?!

Comment: @EdwardBlack oh shucks, I meant once.

Answer (score 1):

First one will be faster, significantly faster (~5 times) than second script with overly complicated tables structure.
But, as already said, script with table gives you more manageable option, easily updated and less error prone. 
It can be made faster though. Since you have adjacent ranges, you don't have to check both edges. Also numeric for is faster than pairs/ipairs.

```
local lvls = {
    {1, "Low Level"},
    {10, "Average Level"},
    {20, "High Level"}
}

local function search_name(user_level)
    local text
    for i=1,#lvls do
        local level = lvls[i]
        if level[1]>user_level then
            return text
        end
        text = level[2]
    end
end

print(search_name(getUserLevel(self)))
```

This option is ~2 times faster than your initial table approach (with getUserLevel moved out of loop).

Comment: Do you have any data on the "5 times" and "2 times" claims?

Comment: Yep. Just ran that piece of code (along with other variants) million times in a loop. Results vary between runs, reaching ~5x and ~2x in extremes, but still quite noticeable on average. Sure, absolute cost doesn't worth mentioning. http://ideone.com/75R3sX